# Problem Viewing Full Binary Tree In VS Code (using JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I run the code for creating a binary tree in VS Code (in JS), it runs, but when I `console.log(tree)`, it only shows `root`, `root.left` and `root.right`. I am unable to see `root.left.right`.

Using Chrome's snippet to run JavaScript, it's easy to see the tree leaves in the console as there are little arrows (pointing right) which you can click and see the whole tree and nodes' properties. This tree is the binary search tree of only 5 values, what if it had 100 values? Or 1000? Or millions?

I am certainly new in working with JS in VS Code, that's why I'm not sure how to do this yet.

One other thing - is there a way to use a debugger in VS Code, like I can in Chrome, by adding breakpoints and running the code step by step manually so I can see where the error is?

For Example:

```js
BST { 
  root: Node { 
    val: 10, 
    left: Node {
      val: 7, 
      left: null, 
      right: [Node] 
    },
    right: Node { 
      val: 15, 
      left: null, 
      right: null 
    }
  }
}
```

See the node with `val:7`, there's a `[Node]` on the right property. I can't click it to see the properties of that specific node, while it's in blue color (in VS Code) but it is just text, I can't see its properties.

I want to see the whole tree like I can in Chrome. Is there a way?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: I *think* what you're running into here is the difference between the console that VS Code uses, which is a generic terminal, and the console that Chrome uses, which has some fancier features. If you're running code in the browser, you can use the [Debugger for Chrome VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome), which will allow you to run full debug in the browser (and see logs in the browser's console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code has a whole section on [debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging). It supports breakpoints, and lets you inspect values (when mousing over variables during a breakpoint) similar to Chrome's console.